# C# Linq - EF, select grouped data having the max value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a many to many table where I store UserId, SectionId, Attempt, Qualification and timestamps. So, the user can have N Attempts by Section but when I evaluate every section only need to take where the Attempt is the max value.
I tried make a join with the keys UserId and SectionId ordering desc by Attempt

```
 var result = await (from exam in db.exams
                            join section in db.sections on exam.SectionId equals section.Id
                            join groupedTable in (from exam2 in db.exams
                                                  group exam2 by new { UserId = exam2.UserId, SectionId = exam2.SectionId, Attempt = exam2.Attempt } into grouped
                                                  select new { UserId = grouped.Key.UserId, SectionId = grouped.Key.SectionId, LastAttempt = grouped.Max(x => x.Attempt) })
                                                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastAttempt)
                                                  .Select(x => new
                                                  {
                                                     UserId = x.UserId,
                                                     SectionId = x.SectionId,
                                                     LastAttempt = x.LastAttempt
                                                  })

                            on new { UserId = exam.UserId, SectionId = section.Id }
                            equals new { UserId = groupedTable.UserId, SectionId = groupedTable.SectionId }
                            select exam)
                            .Distinct()
                            .ToListAsync();
```

also tried this

```
   var result = await (from exam in db.exams
                            join section in db.sections on exam.SectionId equals section.Id
                            select new
                            {
                                UserId = exam.UserId,
                                SectionId = exam.SectionId,
                                Attempt = exam.Attempt
                            })
                            .GroupBy(x => new
                            {
                                x.UserId,
                                x.SectionId,
                                x.Attempt
                            })
                            .Select(x => new
                            {
                                UserId = x.Key.UserId,
                                SectionId = x.Key.SectionId,
                                Attempt = x.Max(x => x.Attempt)
                            })
                            .ToListAsync();
```

but the result is the same:

```
{ UserId = {e56e13b6-28e5-46b2-bd78-f975fd96e1a7}, SectionId = 8, Attempt = 1 }
{ UserId = {e56e13b6-28e5-46b2-bd78-f975fd96e1a7}, SectionId = 10, Attempt = 1 }
{ UserId = {e56e13b6-28e5-46b2-bd78-f975fd96e1a7}, SectionId = 9, Attempt = 1 }
{ UserId = {e56e13b6-28e5-46b2-bd78-f975fd96e1a7}, SectionId = 10, Attempt = 2 }
```

I this example I need to exclude where SectionId = 10 and Attempt = 1

Comment: IMHO Navigation properties are much easier to use than joins, `.Where(e => e.Attempt == e.ParentNav.ChildNav.Max(x => x.Attempt))`

Answer (score 0):

You keep grouping by Attempt, which means every user+section+attempt becomes its own group (probably of size 1)

Remove Attempt from the grouping part of the operation; only group by user and section

It might be clearer to explain using SQL. You are doing this:

```sql
    SELECT user, section, attempt, MAX(attempt) --max is useless here 
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY user, section, attempt --always a group size of 1
```

You need to do this:

```sql
    SELECT user, section, MAX(attempt)
    FROM ...
    GROUP BY user, section
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = await (from exam in db.exams
                        join section in db.sections on exam.SectionId equals 
                        section.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            UserId = exam.UserId,
                            SectionId = exam.SectionId,
                            Attempt = exam.Attempt
                        })
                        .GroupBy(x => new
                        {
                            x.UserId,
                            x.SectionId
                           
                        })
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            UserId = x.Key.UserId,
                            SectionId = x.Key.SectionId,
                            Attempt = x.Max(c => c.Attempt)
                        })
                        .ToListAsync();
```

try this it will work.